# can not able to figure out how to pass params in appolo client usequery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am new to graphql . I am using appolo client wthis is my query

```js
#import "GraphQL/Fragments/BasePost.graphql"
#import "GraphQL/Fragments/PageMetadata.graphql"

query Posts($page: Int, $limit: Int) {
  posts(options: { paginate: { page: $page, limit: $limit } }) {
    data {
      ...BasePost
    }

    meta {
      ...PageMetadata
    }
  }
}

  const { data, loading ,fetchMore  } = useQuery(postsQuery,{page:2,limit:100})
```

but it is not calling the second page